# Identify musical element reminiscent of Pink Floyd

Tags: pink-floyd

I'm listening to [this piece](https://youtu.be/9kf-3mLn1vE?t=35m16s) by Entheogenic.

The part starting from the time shown by the link, has something in it that I'm sure I heard from Pink Floyd, but I can't remember in which song.

Anyway, my musical knowledge is so poor that I can't understand what's happening that made this part so similar to the Pink Floyd one (well I can't remember the song, hope some can) What's happening? Is just a chord progression? Is there a modulation from some key? Does this come from somewhere before both Pink Floyd and Entheogenic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the cover image, it looks like Entheogenic might be explicitly inspired by Pink Floyd.  They are using a number of techniques to produce that "Pink Floyd" mood, but the one that sticks out to me at that point is the use of a synthesizer with a pitch bender that smoothly shifts between widely different pitches.

I'm guessing the song you're thinking of is ["Welcome to the Machine"](https://youtu.be/lt-udg9zQSE?t=5m20s) from *Wish You Were Here* (1975).

This same effect was also widely used in 70's funk.  Kool & the Gang's "[Summer Madness](https://youtu.be/2SFt7JHwJeg?t=40s)" (1974) is a paradigmatic example.